# How to parse a json payload while sending it from producer to consumer topic?

Tags: json, apache-kafka

I want to send a payload from a producer topic to a consumer topic. I've created the channels locally & tried sending payload on producer topic. But the payload is not received on the consumer side.

I think this could be another in JSON formatting I've tried online JSON beautifiers but this is not helping.

Although it's a very slight chance, there is a possibility that there's something wrong with the code and the producer topic is not able to receive the payload. But I'm not able to confirm this.

Comment: Please show your code as a [mcve]. Kafka doesn't care if the JSON is beautified/formatted as long as it's a valid object

Comment: I really wish I could do that. I'm not allowed to paste anything from company codebase. So I don’t know how to produce that code here. I'm a new developer. And have started using stack overflow very recently. So I'm new to the whole process. I'd appreciate if anyone has any suggestions for me.

Comment: You don't need to (and shouldn't) show company code, but without some reproduction of your error, it is hard to help any further. As I said, Kafka itself doesn't care if the data you send is valid JSON, or not. If a consumer does not get data, then chances are you didn't actually `flush()` the producer properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to show code to solve your specific problem, but here is a simple example using [`kcat`](https://github.com/edenhill/kcat/) and `jq`

Producing

```bash
$ kcat -P -b localhost:9092 -t example
{"hello":"world"}
{"hello":"test data"}
```

Consume and parse

```bash
$ kcat -b localhost:9092 -C -t example -u | jq -r .hello
world
test data
```

The Kafka broker will not validate your JSON. The serialization library in your client *might*. So your issue could be any one of the following

- If your serializer failed, and you aren't catching and logging that exception
- You are not sending enough data for the producer buffer to clear, and so you should call `.flush()` method on the producer at some point.
- You have some Kafka authorization enabled on your cluster and your producer is failing to connect/produce.
- Some other connection setting is wrong in your code.

Comment: my bad, there was a msiatke from my end. DUe to incoreect parsing the payload never reached the consumer.
And I found this out through kafdrop, where we can check kafka events. The tool was very helpful. And the wrong format messed up the way the payload was being received. Due to the wrong format the consumer could not process the payload.

Comment: The Kafka broker will not validate your JSON. The serialization library in your client might.
I found this info very helpful. And so i started looking how to checkthe payload in any otehr way. And kafdrop helped. Thanks!